# EBS volume stuck on 'creating' when using Boto API

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ebs

I'm attempting to create and attach a new EBS volume to an existing instance using Boto.  The Boto script is running on the instance itself.

The problem is that the status continuously returns 'creating' much of the time.  (Frustratingly, not always!)  The code snippet is:

```
volume = conn.create_volume(args.ebs_volume_size, instance.placement)

status = ''
while status != 'available':
    status = conn.get_all_volumes([volume.id])[0].status
    print "Volume status: %s" % status
    time.sleep(4)
```

Most of the time, it hangs on 'creating', even though the volume is created and available (it can be seen in the management console as ready to go).  Sometimes, it works fine.  I must be missing something obvious... but what?

Comment: Some quick questions: What Region are you in (PXD, IAD, etc)? Have you contacted AWS support, or tried via their forums?

Comment: You'll probably need to provide a bunch of account related stuff (CustomerId, VolumeId) for this to be diagnosed.

Comment: I am having the same problem... Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Right after you run you create_volume method, call update on the newly created volume.

```
volume = conn.create_volume(args.ebs_volume_size, instance.placement)

while volume.status != 'available':
    time.sleep(5)
    volume.update()
    print volume.status
```